# More concise assignment for elements in a list (Python)?

Tags: python, list, variable-assignment, list-comprehension, python-2.x

How can I do the following in a more concise, "pythonic" way:

```
for element in some_list:
        if some_condition:
                element.some_attr = some_value
```

Comment: I personally think that what you have right now is simple, direct and therefore Pythonic.

Comment: It depends if you want to mutate the original list, or make a new one. In the last case some sort of mapping (or comprehension) can be used.

Comment: From "The Zen of Python" (http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/): "Explicit is better than implicit"

Comment: I agree with @aix that this is just ok. If there would be some `else` statement assigning to the same `element.some_attr` I would go for ternary operator, that is `element.some_attr = some_value if some_condition else other_value`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only thing that's not pythonic in your code is that you're not using [4 spaces for indentation](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/).

“Pythonic” doesn't always mean “concise”; for example the following is shorter, but less readable than your loop:

```
[setattr(e, 'some_attr', some_value) for e in some_list if some_condition]
```

So, stick to the code you have.

Answer (score 0):

```
any(setattr(element, "some_attr", some_value) for element in some_list if some_condition)
```

Not necessarily "more Pythonic" - but more concise. The function call do "any" is just to cause the generator to be consumed - as it is created as a lazy object, and the operations would only be performed when it's elements are fetched.

Comment: Also, `any` works because `setattr` always returns `None`, thus any() consumes the entire iterator. `all` wouldn't have worked. Having to think about these things detracts from the clarity of the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is ok.

May be you can prefer this:

```
for element in some_list:
    element.some_attr = some_value if some_condition else element.some_attr
```

But it does useless assignements...